# getting HTTP Status 500 when location href or when forwarding from Servlet?

Tags: servlets, location, forwarding

I get this error:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
```

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1-b24 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1-b24

when I try to forward from a jsp to another jsp or when I forward in a servlet... The thing is that Y modify some datils from my page and I want to go back to the login-page and log in again to see if the update was successful !... Any ideas on this error ?... Thankx

Comment: Look in the logs for the cause of the NPE. It could be anything; we can't see your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`NullPointerException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is a rather trivial exception and has actually nothing to do with JSP/Servlets, but with basic Java in general (look, it's an exception of `java.lang` package, not of `javax.servlet` package). [It just means](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) that some object is `null` while your code is trying to access/invoke it using the period `.` operator.

Something like:

```
SomeObject someObject = null;
someObject.doSomething(); // NullPointerException!
```

The 1st line of the stacktrace tells you in detail all about the class name, method name and line number where it occurred.

Fixing it is relatively easy. Just make sure that it's not `null` or bypass the access altogether. You should rather concentrate on **why** it is `null` and/or **why** your code is trying to deal with `null`.

Comment: Because the only thing I do is getting a param which tells the kink of operation to execute and then I do the

Comment: getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/welcomeJSF.jsp").forward(request,response);

Comment: The log page doesn't tell me in which line is the NullPointer so I don't know what to do... I don't have so much code typed so as to be kinda confused... So WoW !... I am pieced off !...

Comment: Erm, did you read the part which says *"note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1-b24 logs"* ? In the future comments, please use "edit" link to expand/improve the comment instead of posting a flood of comments in a short time. Comments are open for editing within 5 minutes.

Comment: really apologize... I didn't kn ow what I was pressing... The thing is that I did some debugging and this line is the one that causes the Exception=> getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/welcomeJSF.jsp").forward(request,response); ... Really don't know much...

Comment: So, either `getServletContext()` or `getRequestDispatcher("/welcomeJSF.jsp")` has returned `null`. I'll bet that it's the latter. Now, you need to read [its javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) when and why it would return `null`. Then you should check a basic Servlet tutorial how exactly to dispatch requests properly. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info